# How can i create a file sharing option "anyone with this link" using New Google Drive Android API?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I want to save data programatically without user interaction and share it with other user's app.

By default it creates file with private option. I want to make it "anyone with this link" so that i can use alternet_link to access this document.
I am creating file using createFile function and not using intent(so user doesn't have to do anything).
I have googled it but couldn't find solution.
Please point me to proper api or implementation.

Comment: As mentioned in duplicate question, It is not possible.